# divisibility by 13 loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

For 2 hours, my friends and I have been trying to do our Java homework, but we are stuck. Basically, you input an number `n`, and the program is supposed to show the first `n` numbers that are indivisible 13. Ignore the rest of the code, since the whole homework is one program. It's the last part of the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Loop {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int eingabe,quadrat;
        int i = 0; //ungerade Zahl Zähler
        int i2 = 0; //Quadratzahler Zähler
        int i3 = 0; //Quadratzahl inkrementierer
        int i4 = 0;
        int i5 = 0;
        int zahl = 1;
        int zahl2 = 1;
        int zahl3 = 1;
        System.out.println("Geben Sie eine Zahl ein");
        eingabe = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Das sind die ungeraden Zahlen");

        while (eingabe >i) {
            if (zahl%2 !=0) {
                System.out.print(zahl + " ");
                i++;
            }
            zahl = zahl + i;            
        }

        System.out.println("\nDas sind die Quadratzahlen");
        while (eingabe>i2) {
            quadrat = zahl2 * zahl2;
            if (quadrat%2==0){
                System.out.print(quadrat +" ");
                i2++;
            } else {
                i3++; /*Dieser Zähler ist nur dafür da damit die Zahl mit der gerechnet wird
                        immer um 1 erhöht wird. Ansonsten wäre es eine Dauerschleife weil 1*1 =1 und i2 würde sich nie inkrementieren
                      */
                zahl2 = zahl2 + i3;
            }
            zahl2 = zahl2 + i2;
        }       

        System.out.println("\nDas sind die durch 13 teilbaren zahlen");

        /////THIS IS THE PART ABOUT THE QUESTION        
        while (eingabe >i4) {
            if (zahl3%13 ==0) {
                System.out.print(zahl3 + " ");
                i4++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("wrong");
                zahl3 = zahl3 + i4;
            }
            zahl3 = zahl3 + i4;             
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: very bad way of variable naming, when you post something in SO please keep variable names sensible in general

Comment: The first n numbers divisible by 13 are 1*13, 2*13, 3*13, ..., n*13.

Comment: i would recommend this format of problem explanation: Explain **expected output** and your **acquired output**

Comment: ***durch 13 teilbaren zahlen*** must be done with the variable ***eingabe***

Comment: "Ignore the rest of the code..." couldn't you cut out the irrelevant code instead of posting the whole lot?

Comment: @AndyTurner they need first n indivisible, not divisible

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama that's what I thought until I checked the code and saw that the number was printed when `zahl3%13 ==0`

Comment: @fortran I understand you are trying to put him in right direction, but you could be little nice about how you convey, at least he tried...

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama as far as we know he just pasted some code without bothering to omit irrelevant parts (laziness hint #1). He didn't explain how they came up with that code, din't bother translating variable names to English, what problems are they having or what other alternatives have they tried and why they didn't work. To me the whole thing is a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

The issue come from your loop condition, and how your increase "zahl3", you should increase "zahl3" only after each loop (by 1). 
If you want to see what your code actually do you could print the value of zahl3 at the entry of each loop, so you will see you don't check all numbers.

```
while (eingabe >i4) {
        if (zahl3%13 ==0) {
        System.out.print(zahl3 + " ");
        i4++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("wrong");
            zahl3 = zahl3 + i4; // <== Delete this line 
        }
        zahl3 = zahl3 + i4; // <== change this one to zahl3++;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!  You helped us out a lot!

Comment: @JangoCG You're welcome. If it solved your problem please validate my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First see the problems.

```
   while (eingabe >i4) // infinite loop as i4 is changing only in if condition.
 //It should have a condition where it can break
     {
                    if (zahl3%13 ==0) {
                        System.out.print(zahl3 + " ");
                        i4++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("wrong");
                        zahl3 = zahl3 + i4; // already incremented at end. Not required 
                    }
                    zahl3 = zahl3 + i4; // you making it double of its value            
                }
```

Possible solution

```
    while (eingabe >= zahl3) // A condition where it can break
 {
                if (zahl3%13 ==0) {
                    System.out.println(zahl3 + " correct ");

                } else {
                    System.out.print(zahl3 + " ");
                    System.out.println("wrong");
                  //  zahl3 = zahl3 + i4;
                }

                zahl3++;    // increment it by one     

            }
```

Output: if eingabe is 15

```
1 wrong
2 wrong
3 wrong
4 wrong
5 wrong
6 wrong
7 wrong
8 wrong
9 wrong
10 wrong
11 wrong
12 wrong
13 correct 
14 wrong
15 wrong
```